# How to get metadata type (english) from image

Tags: image, vba, image-processing, metadata

I have a folder which contains lots of photos clicked over an year.
Photos were clicked with different cameras, and the hence names of file are in different formats (follow different templates), I want to organize images by event, and I am thinking to use the date of make  to sort and rename photos according to a logic.
Retrieving the metadata from image is easy as I use this code:

```
Public Sub GetMetadata()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objFSO.Namespace("C:\Users\fabrizio.carboni\Desktop\fotonido\")

For i = 0 To 40
   Debug.Print i, objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items, i)
Next

End Sub
```

Here is my problem the resut is in Italian:

```
 0            Nome
 1            Dimensione
 2            Tipo elemento
 3            Ultima modifica
 4            Data creazione
 5            Data ultimo accesso
 6            Attributi
```

And if I try

```
For Each objFoto In objFolder.Items
    'print file name
    strFotoName = objFoto.Nome
............
```

I get an error, how i can retreive the english name for each metadata name?!??
sorry for the trivial question but I did not find solution even on google.

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions:

**Use the local variables window to get the name of those properties**

[image]

**Use early binding to enable IntelliSense**:

Add Microsoft Shell Automation as a reference (%Windir%\System32\Shell32.dll)

[image]

**Edit 1:**
As per your comment, here's how to print the creation date. Simply switch the old for each loop with this:

```
For Each element In objFolder.Items
Debug.Print (objFolder.GetDetailsOf(element, 4))
Next
```

4 is the index of the creation date. You can do likewise with the other details. More information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787870(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: the date of make is not present, perhaps my question could be simpler: How I can find the list of image metadata (like name, dimension, type, ...) or more someone can let me know hou do you said "data acquizione"

Comment: I've modified my answer. I hope it answers your question.

Comment: thank bat 4 is the date where the file are created (like the moment when it are copying from usb to your PC) and not the date when the photo are taken

Comment: I loop all element, (objFolder.GetDetailsOf(element, 12)) is my date. thank